# Unable to create Table with upper case in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa for my project, it handles creating the database, when i was working on my machine which is windows everything was fine, but when deploying to linux machine the application broke saying table could not be found

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sframele_levelsDB.Store' doesn't exist
```

table name is case sensitive in linux machines and for some reason even I am specifying in my entity the table name to be lowercase jpa is looking for Store not store

```
@Entity
@Table(name="store")
public class Store {
```

I tried to change the name to Store

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Store")
public class Store {
```

but the created table still lowercase, i tried several naming strategies but did not work

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

also tried

```
 spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy` 
`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Table(name="`Store`")
```

instead.